# How was Zaphod Beeblebrox five hundred thousand light years away from the Sun and still in the Milky way?

Tags: the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy

In chapter 4 of the Hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy, the first part of the six book series it reads,

> Far away on the opposite spiral arm of the Galaxy, five hundred
>   thousand light-years from the star Sol, Zaphod Beeblebrox, President of the Imperial Galactic Government, sped across the seas of Damogran, his ion drive delta boat winking and flashing in the Damogran sun.

The milky way is estimated to be about [100,000 light years](https://imagine.gsfc.nasa.gov/features/cosmic/milkyway_info.html) wide.So 500,000 light years from any point in the milky way should be outside the galaxy.Is it an error in the book or am I missing something?

Comment: It's just an error in the book. It should (presumably) read 50,000

Comment: The out-of-universe explanation is that HHGG was originally a parody of bad SF tropes. It's supposed to be over the top, and inaccuracies only reinforce this. Or you can blame it on the Infinite Improbability Drive.

Comment: Vell, Zaphod's just zis guy, you know?

Comment: Spencer/Valorum: Short answers are still answers. Post them as such.

Comment: @JimboJonny they’re not answers in that neither has any evidence to back them up. They’re just comments pointing to potential answers and as such are perfectly fine as comments.

Comment: I think this falls under the same category as the Martians in Mars Attacks! needing nitrogen as we need oxygen, thus the helmets and the one non-helmeted Martian chewing some sort of gum. Science and logic are deliberately distorted or mis-stated for the sake of humor; in the case of Mars Attacks!, satirizing the misread science and plot holes common in many 1950s alien invasion movies.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - It that's the case then that just makes them poor answers that wouldn't likely get upvoted much or accepted, or might even be called out or downvoted. **Which is actually an extremely important reason to have them as answers if that's the case**. The differentiation between "answer" and "comment" doesn't lay in quality level of the answer.

Comment: @JimboJonny there’s an important distinction in my opinion, and that of our site last time it can up on meta, of an answer and a comment pointing to an answer. The two above fall into the latter category in my opinion. That said this site it a lot more lax on “‘answers’ in comments” than most.

Comment: @JimboJonny There is also a distinction between an answer and speculation.  Unless Valorum has facts to back his comment up, it remains speculation.  And speculation does not an answer make.

Comment: Belgium, man!!  The maths were wrong....

Comment: @PeterM - Even if it were 100% wrong and based on nothing it would be an answer. Wrong answers are a thing. Rightness/wrongness does not determine whether it's categorized as an "answer" vs "comment". **That's specifically why** answers need to go in as answers regardless of correctness or weakness of citation. So wrong or speculatory ones can be questioned, downvoted, attacked, defended, possibly fixed/cited, and organized at the bottom of the page from the downvotes if they are not fixed or improved rather than hanging as-is right under the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *There is a theory which states that if ever anyone discovers exactly what the Universe is for and why it is here, it will instantly disappear and be replaced by something even more bizarre and inexplicable.*
>
> *There is another theory which states that this has already happened.*

*- The Restaurant at the End of the Universe*

The out-of-universe explanation is that HHGG was originally a parody of bad SF tropes. It's supposed to be over the top, and inaccuracies only reinforce this. Don't try to make comedy consistent.

Or rather, if you like, blame it on the Infinite Improbability Drive.

Comment: Perhaps, like in *Futurama*, future voters decided to change the speed of light. Although apparently they found it worthwhile to reduce it rather than increase it, possibly to slow down the spread of bad news.